# Sqlalchemy I can't combine two tables

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need to merge two tables, User and Post. In the final version, you need the entire selection from the Post and username of the User. The models are linked by a foreign key

I solved the problem with SQL:

```
SELECT post.*, public.user.username
FROM post
JOIN public.user ON post.author_id=public.user.id
```

,
but I can't transfer it to sqlalchemy in any way.
My query:

```
query = select(Post, User.username).join(User).filter(Post.author_id == User.id)
result = await session.execute(query)
return {'status': 200, 'data': result.scalars().all()}
```

does not work, I have already tried many options using join. Nothing helped. I can't use Relationship

Answer (score 1):

If you use `scalars()` the result won't contain `User.username`.  You need to just use `execute` in this case.  You can also put the `ON` condition in the second argument of `join` instead of in `filter` which would place it in the `WHERE` clause.

```py
stmt = select(Post, User.username).join(User, Post.author_id == User.id)
for post, username in session.execute(stmt).all():
    print (post, username)
```